# Freelancer.com retrieving bids: HTTP 401, "You must be logged in to perform this request"

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, freelancer.com-api

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong interfacing with [this API](https://developers.freelancer.com/docs/projects/bids#bids-get) of Freelancer.com, retrieving bids:

I'm sending a GET request to [https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/bids/?projects[]=36483622&projects[]=36483620](https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/bids/?projects%5B%5D=36483622&projects%5B%5D=36483620) with the following headers:

```
[
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]
```

I'm getting HTTP 401 returned, with the body as follows:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "You must be logged in to perform this request",
    "error_code": "RestExceptionCodes.NOT_AUTHENTICATED",
    "request_id": "45b290aa21a0fabe9effb0c6c5294097"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My token works fine when I try to retrieve projects via this URL:

[https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?jobs[]=3](https://www.freelancer.com/api/projects/0.1/projects/active/?jobs%5B%5D=3)

What does it mean I need to be logged in? Doesn't the token do that? How do I retrieve bids on projects? Can I only retrieve bids on projects that I posted? What about bids that I submitted?

Thanks

Comment: The cURL example request listed on the documentation page you referred to, uses `--header 'freelancer-oauth-v1: <oauth_access_token>'` ...?

Comment: Where are you getting `$token` from? Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: "*My token works fine when I try to retrieve projects via this URL:*" That's probably because that particular endpoint doesn't require authentication (since I was able to open it in my browser) and the server is disregarding your `Authorization` header entirely.

Comment: https://developers.freelancer.com/docs/authentication/using-access-tokens

Comment: next time you need help debugging, please provide more of the source code. there might be additional issues with your request, which is not shown in the code you shared. For example, if your code also use a `CURLOPT_POST=>1` or `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>...` in this request, that would be another issue with the code, but i have no idea, because you don't provide the curl_setopt options you used (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: don't set a `Content-Type` if your request doesn't have a body. your request doesn't, so remove the Content-Type. (also emptystring is not valid json. `1` or `[]` would be valid JSON, but you're not sending any JSON.)

2: the header is called  `freelancer-oauth-v1: <oauth_access_token>`  so try

```php
[
    'freelancer-oauth-v1: ' . $token,
    // remove this line, it does not belong in GET requests: 'Content-Type: application/json'
]
```